# Scala case class: Is public var member possible?

Tags: scala, var, access-modifiers, case-class

Scala noob here, but while learning about `case` classes, I see the members are by default read-only. However, if you add `var`, they become private; and there is no `public` access modifier. Any way to have a `case` class with a public `var` that you can therefore modify directly?
I know this may not be what a `case` class is intended for, but I am wondering nonetheless (since having a `var` member itself is possible).

Comment: A `final case class Data(var i: Int)` should be _"valid"_ and `i` should be public, not private. - However, this may break any code that uses `Data` assuming a well-behaved immutable case class, should not pass any code review, and may make a kitty cry.

Comment: _If you add var, they become private;_ Where did you get that info? That's not true.

Comment: If you need to mutate a case class like that, you probably don't need it, but also case classes come with the `copy` method, which allows. you to create a copy of the cc instance with updated values. Any property you don't specify in copy will not be changed. I.e `case class Foo(bar: Int, fii: Int); val foo = Foo(2, 3); val newFoo = foo.copy(bar=1)` will output `Foo(1, 3)`

Comment: `vars` are public. They just ... should not be used. _Especially_ with case classes. Avoid them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be drawn to a wrong conclusion by Scala's syntax: the fact that you don't have a `public` qualifier is because `public` is the default in Scala and you explicitly have to opt out with `private` or some scoped variation.

The following code demonstrates that a `var` in a `case class` is accessible and works as expected:

```
case class Foo(var mutable: Int)

val foo = Foo(42)

foo.mutable = 47

assert(foo == Foo(47))
```

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/us6QhDsiTVeTrL8Xwo12JA).

Note that if you explicit make the `mutable` field explicitly `private`, the code no longer compiles:

```
case class Foo(private var mutable: Int)

val foo = Foo(42)

foo.mutable = 47

assert(foo == Foo(47))
```

The code above will cause the following compile-time error: `variable mutable cannot be accessed as a member of ...` (again, you can see that in action [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/LawNb2h6S7ulKoca9bNqww)).

---

With that said, `case class`es are usually meant to represent immutable data. In doing so, they introduce some synthetic method that you probably won't need or might get in the way (e.g. the `copy` method). If you want to represent mutable data, you might want to see if a simple `class` might represent a better fit for your use case.